# Primefaces <p:printer> treeTable's content - not all columns printed

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, printing

I need to print a treeTable's content. 
The problem is that not all columns are displayed/printed. 
The treeTable have 4 columns and only 2 are printed (truncating)

How to print the complete treeTable's content? 
Is possible to customize page layout (portrait/landscape)?

```
<p:commandButton value="Print" 
                 type="button"
                 icon="fa fa-print">
    <p:printer target="treeTable" />
</p:commandButton>

<p:treeTable id="treeTable"
             value="#{myMB.root}" 
             var="obj"
             resizableColumns="true" 
             style="width:100%">

<p:column headerText="Column Label 1" style="width:40%">
    <h:outputText value="#{obj.label1}" />
</p:column>
<p:column headerText="Column Label 2" style="width:20%">
    <h:outputText value="#{obj.label2}"  />
</p:column>
<p:column headerText="Column Label 3" style="width:20%;text-align: center;">
    <h:outputText style="float: center;" value="#{obj.label3}" />
</p:column>
<p:column headerText="Column Label 4" style="width:20%">
    <h:outputText style="float: left;" value="U$" rendered="#{not empty obj.label4}" />
    <h:outputText style="float: right;" value=" #{obj.label4}" rendered="#{not empty obj.label4}" />
</p:column>
```

Primefaces 5.3 and Wildfly 10
[]'s

Comment: include in your code the Columns

Comment: it's used to see if there's any problem in the data that you display

Comment: columns included @YagamiLight.

 the data is displayed correctly in the web application. 

 the problem occurs when printing